# Double sign-in required with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've got a Rails 3.0.9 application using Devise 1.4.9.  I'm having a bit of a problem with the login screens.  I think I understand the problem as I've previously fixed a similar issue in a C application.  But this time I'm just using devise so it is harder to just fix the source code ...

The basic pattern is I log out of the application, which takes me to a URL such as this: http://10.0.0.25:3000/devise/users/sign_in

I then go home and come back to work the next day, with the above address still open in the browser.  I type in the password, but I just get a message saying my session has expired, and I have to re-enter the password.

Making an educated guess, when the user is shown the sign_in page, devise creates a new session which is not currently logged in.  When the user submits the page, devise checks the session exists, and then checks the credentials.  For security reasons, the credentials will not work for an expired (or unknown) session.

The fix in the C application was to allow a very long timeout for sessions that had never been logged in.  Once a session is logged in, it does need to be logged out after an inactivity delay that is relatively short, so just changing `config.timeout_in` wouldn't be enough.

**EDIT:** I've noticed by messing around with the timeout set down to 1 minute that the not-logged-in session timeout does not change to one minute (in fact I haven't really noticed whether it has changed at all...)  So there must be something else that does this.

Also I realised when a session is not logged in, there is no time stored within the session cookie, so I don't even know exactly how the server determines the session age (I don't have a server-side sessions table).